# Multi-part identifer issue when joining table to function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**THE QUESTION:**

My join is not working as expected:

```
join db1.function1(t1.id) f1 on f1.id = t1.id
```

The error message is:

```
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
The multi-part identifier 't1.id' could not be found.
```

This bit `(t1.id)` is underlined with a red squiggly line.

I get the same issue when I try to use `cross apply`.

The function is a table-valued function, so returns a table.

---

**FULL QUERY EXAMPLE:**

```
select t1.*, f1.*
FROM db1.dbo.table1 t1
join db1.dbo.function1(t1.id) f1 on f1.id = t1.id
```

---

**SIMPLIFIED VERSION OF THE FULL FUNCTION:**

```
USE [DB1]

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[function1](@id int)
RETURNS @return_table TABLE (
    id INT, 
    col1 INT,
    col2 VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- ...
    -- do all sorts of stuff here to get needed data, temp tables, unions, joins, inserts, selects etc
    -- ...

    INSERT INTO @return_table (id, col1, col2)
    select distinct id, col1,
    (
        select isnull(cast(col2 as varchar(3)),'NULL')+','
        from @tbl2 t2
        where t2.id = t1.id
        for xml path('')
    ) col2
    from @tbl1 a1

    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: WHat is db1? If it's the database name, then you are missing one qualifier there: the schema. It should be more like: `db1.dbo.function1`. Same goes for qualifying `table1`.

Comment: @marceln I think db1 is the schema not the database.

Comment: Sorry, I have 'dbo' in my actual script, forgot to type it into the question.  Updated.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the structure of `table1`? Does it have an `id` column?

Comment: Show us the db1.dbo.function1 function, the source code of the function

Comment: @DavidG, yes, it has an id column.  In-fact, if I do an join to a normal table, instead of a table valued function, it works fine.

Comment: @zaratustra, the function works fine on it's own.  if I type in a static value into the functions input parameter, the query works fine.  But I need to use a dynamic value as shown in the script above.

Comment: You are trying to join onto a function using a column from `table1` before the join has actually happened.

Comment: @DavidG, clearly I am doing this wrong.  How should I be doing this?

Comment: You need to tell us what the function does then.

Comment: @DavidG, the function returns 1 row, 3 columns with security details based on the id given.

Comment: Can you post the function, or something similar?

Comment: @DavidG, it's 130'ish lines...  I'll probably scare everyone away.  I'll post anyway.  Give me a few moments.

Comment: Just the rough outline is enough.

Comment: @DavidG, I've tried adding a simplified version of the function to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Hi So basically you are looking to perform a `INNER JOIN`. The problem you are fasing is that you are using a Function. What you should be using to achieve is a `CROSS JOIN`. If left Join is desired, you could use a `OUTER JOIN`

There is a great artical that explains in detail that has helped me in the past and can be navigated to by following this link. [ClickMe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you). Search for `Use case 5: APPLY and TVFs`

I have also written a code that may be of some assistance for the immediate request

**Test Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Test1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Test1
END
CREATE TABLE Test1 (Tbl1ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                Name VARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO Test1
VALUES('ABCD1'),
     ('ABCD2'),
     ('ABCD3'),
     ('ABCD4'),
     ('ABCD5'),
     ('ABCD6')

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Test2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Test2
END
CREATE TABLE Test2 (Tbl2ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                Name VARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES('ABCD1'),
     ('ABCD2'),
     ('ABCD4'),
     ('ABCD5')

GO
```

**TV Function:**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ufn_TVFTable2]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_TVFTable2]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_TVFTable2 (@Name NVARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM Test2
    WHERE Name = @Name

GO
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT t.*,tf.*
FROM Test1 AS T 
CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_TVFTable2(T.name) AS tf
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ufn_TVFTable2]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_TVFTable2]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Test1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Test1
END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Test2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Test2
END
```

**Your Query would look like below:**

```
SELECT t1.*,
       f1.*
FROM db1.dbo.table1 AS t1 
CROSS APPLY db1.dbo.function1(t1.id) AS f1
```

**Usage Example 2:**

```
;WITH cte_table1(ID) AS
(

SELECT 82938382 AS ID UNION ALL
SELECT 82938383 AS ID UNION ALL
SELECT 82938384 AS ID UNION ALL
SELECT 82938385 AS ID 

) 
SELECT t1.*,
       f1.*
FROM db1.dbo.table1 AS t1 
CROSS APPLY db1.dbo.function1(t1.id) AS f1
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried `cross apply` as follows `CROSS APPLY db1.dbo.function1(t1.id) AS f1`, but I get the following error `Incorrect syntax near '.'.`.  I've tried hard code the value for for function as in `CROSS APPLY db1.dbo.function1(82938382) AS f1`, it works perfectly...

Comment: Got it, Please change the function and add the below line before return. SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM @return_table. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: @oshirowanen Can you please tell me what happens when you do
SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.function1(82938382)
Also Please confirm ID column exists in db1.dbo.table1

Comment: `SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.function1(82938382)` works fine and it returns a single row with 3 columns

Comment: So 82938382 is derived from a column (ID) in db1.dbo.table1 Table?

Comment: A static value works fine as a function input value, it just doesn't seem to like alias.column_name as a function input value.  as in t1.id.

Comment: Can you please try without the fully qualified names please. Remove db1. Just a guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58245/discussion-between-gouri-shankar-aechoor-and-oshirowanen).

Comment: @oshirowanen Can you please try without the fully qualified names please. Remove db1. Just a guess.
I have added Usage Example 2: to the answer, Please confirm if this works. If it does then there is something else that going on. Also, please accept the answer and UpVote if you like my solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to join onto a function using a column from `table1` before the join has actually happened. Think of the return of `function1` as an atomic operation which you are then joining to `table1`. So at that point, SQL doesn't know what the value of the `id` column is.

Assuming `function1` does not return a table, you probably wanted to do this:

```
SELECT t1.*, db1.dbo.function1(t1.id)
FROM db1.dbo.table1 t1
```

Comment: That seems very logical, but I am getting the following error `Cannot find either column "db1" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.dbo.function1", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, the function is a table valued function, so returns a table.  Which is why I was trying the join.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want to achieve without a cursor or something equally hacky.

Comment: Your function should either return multiple rows (i.e. 1 for every ID) or split into 3 functions, 1 for each column and use my SQL above.

Comment: Yes, at the moment, it returns 1 row per id.  but the join still doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried adding a simplified version of the function to the question above.